# HTML5 video tag support on blackberry

Tags: html, html5-video

I am developing an app in HTML5 for blackberry os 7+ devices,its an app like youtube.here i am using .mp4 for playing video in video tag,but most of the time the video doesn't play on the device.I am using hardsub videos like subtitles are already embedded in videos. 
can any one please tell me why most of videos are not playing on device but playing on PC.

Thanks in advance!
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog post for encoding recommendations for Blackberry.

http://blog.zencoder.com/2010/09/30/how-to-encode-video-for-mobile-use/